# Remove background from LaTeX table

Tags: tables, beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am creating a Beamer presentation with the `metropolis` package and I use the `ctable` package to include tables. However, the background of the slides is not exactly white, it has a nuance of colour to improve visibility.

After typesetting, you can clearly see that the background of the tables is whiter than the slide background. It is not a huge inconvenient, but I was wondering if there is any way to remove the table background. I have checked the `colortbl` package, but I couldn't find anything.

This is a working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            \ctable[
                caption = My caption,
                label = theLabel,
                pos = tb
            ]{ccccc}{
            }{\FL
            \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} &   \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \ML
            AAA & - & 0.59 &    1.19    & 6,85 \NN
            ABC  & 11.6 - 19.4\%    & 0.98  & 1.29  & 6.20 \NN
            CDA & 10.8 - 21.2\%  & 1.02 & 1.33  & 6.12 \LL
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you should provide small complete document which we can test and see, what is your problem ...

Comment: Hmm, the `bgopacity` key is disabled when `tikz` is loaded, which of course it is for the `beamer` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you would use the `bgopacity=0` key to make the `\ctable` background transparent.  However, that feature is disabled when `tikz` is loaded, which is the case for the `beamer` document class.

Thus, the alternative is to set the `framebg` (frame background color) key to the same as the `metropolis` theme, here guessed as `.98 .98 .98`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            \ctable[
                caption = My caption,
                label = theLabel,
                pos = tb,
                bgopacity=0,% DISABLED
                framebg= .98 .98 .98
            ]{ccccc}{
            }{\FL
            \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} &   \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \ML
            AAA & - & 0.59 &    1.19    & 6,85 \NN
            ABC  & 11.6 - 19.4\%    & 0.98  & 1.29  & 6.20 \NN
            CDA & 10.8 - 21.2\%  & 1.02 & 1.33  & 6.12 \LL
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I added it in the preamble so it affects all the tables: `\setupctable{framebg=.98 .98 .98}`

Comment: The background colour from the metropolis color theme is `bg=black!2`, so a very good guess :) A small detail: Your answer sounds like beamer would load tikz, this might be misleading, as beamer "only" uses `pgf`.